# Language/"GUI Builder" which executes on most windows computers

Tags: windows, user-interface

I am trying to create a very simple GUI which will run on most windows computers simply by double clicking the exe only without any additional requirements such as framework. What language would you suggest I do this in and are there any available "GUI builders" which can make this app quickly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your app use db? Does it read/write to file system? Do you expect the user to have a browser? Why not use a web app?

Comment: My app is basically a drop down list with dates on it, when selected a text box is populated with a description of what happened on that date and a button is updated so that when pressed it loads the relevant pdf document. I tried to use visual c++ and got a .NET framework error for this and then tried to use C++ Qt and had a huge (filled with 10 dll's) for a hello world example! so I thought that there must be a more efficient method of doing this which is simple for the end user.

Comment: Will the plain winapi in c not give me any sort of errors such as .NET framework which I have had with almost everything in the past? Are there any IDE's which will help me build this GUI "physically" rather than programming it all? Also, forgot to mention, a desktop GUI is preferred for the application.

Comment: Delphi is a good choice

Comment: There is a product called PureBasic: http://www.purebasic.com/introduction_windows.php as well others mentioned here:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_graphical_user_interface_builders_and_rapid_application_development_tools .May be you want to take a look if it does what you want. I would just go with HTML/JavaScript if possible. Most products on the above references may or may not work on Windows 8, 8.1,etc.

Comment: @Jeff Yes. The question should be closed as primarily opinion based. Comments are the vehicle for expressing those opinions.

Answer (score 0):

WPF. The framework ships with any modern Windows version and it's a joy to work with.

Comment: That's just your opinion.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have seen that it works with visual studio. If I make a GUI with this using visual studio will the exe work fine on the majority of windows computers (xp, vista, windows 7, windows 8) without saying something like .NET framework required?

Comment: Yes. But he is correct, not XP.  Also, it is version dependent so you may want to stick to 3.5 for maximum coverage.  I would look into which versions shipped with which OSes.

Comment: SO is all about absolutes. Pure opinion questions should be closed.